# how to set nested object properties in Backbone.Collection.get()?

Tags: backbone.js, nested

I have an object with another nested object which I would like to modify using Backbone's .get() functionality. According to the docs, I can set the root level object keys, but is there a way to alter the nested properties as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set/get nested values but it will act as a replace not an update.

```
model = {'foo': {'bar': 'baz', 'qux': 'foo'}};
model.get('foo');                 // {'bar': 'baz', 'qux': 'foo'}
model.set('foo', {'baz': 'qux'});
model.get('foo');                 // {'baz': 'qux'}
```